# bash script | URL health check | mail sending option

Tags: linux, bash, shell

We need to health check a URL every minute of the clock.

Algorithm of bash script is following:

```
if (url is not up)
  send mail
  wait for 5 minutes 
  if (still not up)
    send mail again and keep on doing it 
else
  nothing
```

My logic is following:

```
#!/bin/bash
IP="192.168.XX.XXX"
URL="http://$IP:YYYY"
CCMAIL="abc@def.com"
TOMAIL="abc@def.com"
STATUSCODE=$(curl -o /dev/null --silent --head --write-out '%{http_code}\n' $URL)
NOWENTRY=$(date +"%d-%m-%Y  %r")
NOWLOG=$(date +"%d-%m-%Y")

if [ $STATUSCODE -ne "200" ]
then
        echo "$IP URL: $URL was down at $NOWENTRY" >> "path/log_$NOWLOG.txt"
        #send mail in one line no timing logic out here   
fi
```

Note: I have put this script in crontab to execute every minute of the clock.

Comment: I have formatted your post for you, please do that yourself next time. Note that you don't need to add `<br>` tags in your post. Also, your question lacks **expected vs. observed behavior** making it difficult to see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
if [ "$STATUSCODE" -ne "200" ]
then
    msg="$IP URL: $URL was down at $NOWENTRY"
    echo "$msg" >> "path/log_$NOWLOG.txt"
    # send email
    echo "$msg" | mailx -c "$CCEMAIL" -s "$URL down" "$TOEMAIL"
    sleep 5m
    # re-spawn this script.
    exec "$0"
fi
```

Comment: My script was put in crontab having time gap of 1 minute.Till the time 1st script is sleeping for next five minutes.Cron tab would have executed executed four times which means four mails are being fired. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: You are correct, but if you want to be notified every 5 minutes, why are you running your script every 1 minute? You don't need 5 copies of your script running simultaneously. For a cron script, just remove the `sleep` and `exec` commands.

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be `!=` when comparing strings?

Comment: we're comparing numbers here. test it: `STATUSCODE="  200  "; [ "$STATUSCODE" = "200" ] && echo strings equal || echo strings not equal; [ "$STATUSCODE" -eq "200" ] && echo numbers equal || echo numbers not equal`